# Solvable queries in muZ

Tags: z3

I want to use z3 for BMC using muZ. Maybe I am missing something concerning the definition of the satisfiability of a query. However, in the following case I have the example of a query that is not satisfiable (i.e., returns "false"), but when adding an extra constraint(which effectively gives the satisfying assignment), a valid assignment is returned.

Is there any documentation helping to understand the exact semantics of the muZ language extension of z3?

Thanks and best regards!!

Executing the following .smt2-file with Z3 version 4.3.2 leads to the following result:

```
formula undetermined in model: (= (head query!0_0_n) (state c1 1))
sat
false
sat
(let ((a!1 (insert (state c1 1) (insert (state c2 0) (insert (state c1 0) nil))))
      (a!2 (TransClosure (insert (state c2 0) (insert (state c1 0) nil)))))
  (and (TransClosure a!1) a!2 (TransClosure (insert (state c1 0) nil))))
```

The corresponding .smt2-file is:

```
;; Application of z3Mu for BMC of EFSM
;; Behavior of EFSM is defined recursively as a predicate over finite sequences (Lists) of states

;; Declaration of state space
(declare-datatypes () ((Control c1 c2)))
(declare-datatypes () ((State (state (cstate Control) (var Int)))))

;; Definition of transition relation and initial state
(declare-rel Trans (State State))
(declare-var pre State) 
(declare-var post State)
(rule (=> (and (= (cstate pre) c1) (= (cstate post) c2) (= (+ (var pre) 0) (var post))) (Trans post pre)))
(rule (=> (and (= (cstate pre) c2) (= (cstate post) c1) (= (+ (var pre) 1) (var post))) (Trans post pre)))

;; Definition of fixed-point closure
(declare-var init State)
(declare-var trace (List State))

(declare-rel Init (State))
(rule (Init (state c1 0)))

(declare-rel TransClosure ((List State)))
(rule (=> (and (Trans (head trace) (head (tail trace))) (TransClosure (tail trace)))
      (TransClosure trace)))
(rule (=> (Init init) (TransClosure (insert init nil))))


;; Query for a witness which is satifiable in three steps
;; Query without explicit witness construction fails
(query (and (= (head trace) (state c1 1))
            (TransClosure trace)
            )
  :print-answer true)
;; Same query with explicit witness succeeds
(query (and (= (head trace) (state c1 1))
            (TransClosure trace)
            (= trace (insert (state c1 1) (insert (state c2 0) (insert (state c1 0) nil))))
            )
 :print-answer true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "formula undetermined in model" message indicates a bug in Z3.
The bug is that Z3 accepted the input as-is without complaints. It should have rejected the example when using the PDR backend engine. The PDR backend engine has support for arithmetic, Booleans and non-optimized for Bit-vectors, and some support for algebraic data-types. It does not support accessors (head, tail) for algebraic datatypes and I have now added a check that reports an error before invoking search and points to the use of unsupported accessors. 
The unstable branch of Z3 contains the fix.

It is possible to rewrite your example using only "insert" instead of "head" "tail".
For example replace (head t) by 's1' and replace 't' elsewhere by '(insert s t)'.

You can use either pure Horn clauses in SMT-LIB2 with the (set-logic HORN) command to invoke one of available Horn clause solvers or you can use the fixedpoint extension syntax which has some conveniences for declaring variables. There are several backends. The main ones are:
- 'datalog': Hash-table based Datalog solver. Relations must be over finite domain variables
- 'pdr': Relations must be over Booleans, arithmetic, bit-vectors and/or algebraic data-types.
- 'bmc': bounded model checking unfolding of the horn clauses corresponding to the transition relation.
Other engines are also present, but these are the main ones to consider.

The semantics of HORN clauses in SMT-LIB2 is the same as SMT-LIB2 semantics. There is no special semantics, but the Horn solvers will only be able to handle a conjunction of formulas that 
correspond to Horn clauses. Your example can be expressed using only Horn clauses: each rule is an implication, and the query corresponds to a negated clause (negate the query and assert it together with the other clauses. When the resulting set of clauses is unsatsifiable, then the query is feasible; when the resulting set of clauses is satisfiable, then the query is infeasiable).